# Instance reactjs class from html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so my question is can i call simple react class like this

```
var myTable = React.createClass({

    render:function () {

        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Test 123</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

from main html..with line like this..
I want to call him with something like that

```
<myTable/>....
```

Comment: JSX is not HTML - you need to render your component using JavaScript.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use reactjs element as HTML element.

you have to use

```
ReactDom.render(<myTable/>, document.querySelector('your div where you want to add this react element') )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JS to render your component.

For example (based closely on the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html)):

```
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(
    <myTable/>,
    document.getElementById('example')
  );
</script>
```